# QGIS use relations in expressions (for symbol and print composer)

Tags: qgis, expression, relates

I have a shapefile layer a relation linking data from a csv file. This is a one to many relationship where a parcel could have multiple entries from the csv.

How do I reference that data in expressions and print? In my print composer I want to list an attribute for each referenced entry attached to a parcel, and I also want to reference the data in symbology.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to reference the data in symbology?

Comment: Sorry, I meant using the data to control how a feature is styled. I figured it out. I used the aggregate_relation function using a count aggregate to find if a related feature was present.